# Reproduce RStudio workspace and variable visualization in Atom for Python language

Tags: python, rstudio, atom-editor, workspace

I recently switched from R to Python, and thus switched from RStudio to Atom. One thing I liked with RStudio was the possibility to have a little window to visualize the variables (the workspace), as well as rapidly open dataframe in the software. Thus, I was wondering if there was a setting in Atom or an existing package that could reproduce this RStudio feature for the Python language?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure just how recently you switched over, but as of [a week ago](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200716783-RStudio-Release-History) RStudio's latest 1.4 update enabled a [whole bunch of Python support](https://blog.rstudio.com/2020/10/07/rstudio-v1-4-preview-python-support/). Here's what my simultaneous R/Python workspace looks like when I'm using both now, and it's great for translating that old R code into Python.

[image: three-panel RStudio layout with R in one, Python in the center, and Python objects shown in the environments pane plus a matplotlib output in the plots pane]